# High school calculus variables problem

Tags: calculus

$$x^3+2x^2+cx+d$$
The question is to solve for $c$ and $d$ with a point of inflexion at $(4,-7)$. 
I am not sure where to start.
thanks.

Comment: Something seems wrong. The only point of inflection is at $x=-\frac{2}{3}$. So we cannot have a point of inflection at $(-4,7)$. The problem would make sense if we had say $x^3+cx^2+2x+d$, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

So what we want is $f^{\prime}(x) = 3x^{2} + 4x + c = 0$, but $f^{\prime \prime}(x) = 6x + 44$  is either greater than $0$ on both sides of $(4, -7)$ or less than $0$ around $(4, -7)$.

You then want to consider $-7 = 64 + 32 + 4c + d$.

Now evaluate $f^{\prime}(4)$. You should be able to solve for $c$ and $d$.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks a lot ml0105

Comment: Glad I could help!